# SparkSQL: How to query a column with datatype: List of Maps

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with column of array (or list) with each element being a map of String, complex data type (meaning String, nested map, list etc. In a way you may assume column data type is similar to `List[Map[String,AnyRef]]`)

Now I want to query on this table like:

```
select * from the tableX where column.<any of the array element>['someArbitaryKey'] in ('a','b','c')
```

How can I represent `<any of the array element>` in the Spark SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to [transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/sql/index.html#transform) the list of maps into a list of booleans, where each boolean indicates if the respective map contains the wanted key (`k2` in the code below). After that all we have to check if the boolean array contains at least one true element.

```sql
select * from tableX where array_contains(transform(col1, map->map_contains_key(map,'k2')), true)
```

I have assumed that the name of the column holding the list of maps is `col1`.

The second parameter of the `transform` function could be replaced by any expression that returns a boolean value. In this example [map_contains_key](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/sql/index.html#map_contains_key) is used, but any check resulting in a boolean value would work.

A bit unrelated: I believe that the data type of the map cannot be `Map[String,AnyRef]` as there is no [encoder](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Encoder.html) for `AnyRef` available.